# How to read specific data from message from kafka with Spring-kafka @KafkaListener?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

My task is to read events from multiple different topics (class of all data in all topics is "Event"). This class contains field "data" (Map) which carries specific for each topic data, that can be deserialized to specific class (e.g. to "DeviceCreateEvent" or smth.). I can create consumers for each topic with @KafkaListener on methods with parameter type "Event". But in this case firstly i have to event.getData() and deserialize it into specific class, so I will get code duplication in all consumer methods. Is there any way to get in annotated consumer method already deserialized object to specific class?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking.

If you have a different `@KafkaListener` for each topic/event type, and use JSON, the framework will automatically tell the message converter the type the data should be converted to; see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion).

> Although the Serializer and Deserializer API is quite simple and flexible from the low-level Kafka Consumer and Producer perspective, you might need more flexibility at the Spring Messaging level, when using either @KafkaListener or Spring Integration. To let you easily convert to and from org.springframework.messaging.Message, Spring for Apache Kafka provides a MessageConverter abstraction with the MessagingMessageConverter implementation and its JsonMessageConverter (and subclasses) customization. You can inject the MessageConverter into a KafkaTemplate instance directly and by using AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean definition for the @KafkaListener.containerFactory() property. The following example shows how to do so: ...
>
> On the consumer side, you can configure a JsonMessageConverter; it can handle ConsumerRecord values of type byte[], Bytes and String so should be used in conjunction with a ByteArrayDeserializer, BytesDeserializer or StringDeserializer. (byte[] and Bytes are more efficient because they avoid an unnecessary byte[] to String conversion). You can also configure the specific subclass of JsonMessageConverter corresponding to the deserializer, if you so wish.